# Problem about the golden ratios and circles.

Tags: geometry

Here is a geometry problem that is driving me nuts!  I feel like I am missing something (the author glosses over proving the part I am having trouble with - really makes me feel dumb), and the problem is very easy to state.

Problem: Start with two small central circles of unit diameter. Then find the radius $R$ of the two circles on their left and right. The requirement is that there exists a pair of congruent circles (dotted) that are simultaneously tangent to all the other circles.

The problem also states that repeated use of the Pythagorean theorem reveals that $R_1$ is the golden ratio.  I have come up with three equations (one of them is not from the Pythagorean theorem) in three unknowns:

1. $\quad 2 \cdot R_1+1 = R_2 + h$
2. $\quad (R_1+1)^2 + h^2 = (R_1+R_2)^2$
3. $\quad (1/2)^2 + h^2 = (R_2+1/2)^2$

A linear system of three equations in three unknowns would be easy to solve, but this isn’t that unfortunately.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Diagram of setup]

Answer (score 3):

The equations are correct, and all that's missing is the last step to solve them for $R_1$. It is not a linear system, but similar techniques of elimination work in this case, too.

> 1. $\quad 2 R_1+1 = R_2 + h$
> 2. $\quad (R_1+1)^2 + h^2 = (R_1+R_2)^2$
> 3. $\quad (1/2)^2 + h^2 = (R_2+1/2)^2$

Eliminating $h$ between 1. and 3. by rearranging 1. and squaring then adding the equations:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
(2 R_1+1-R_2)^2 + 1/4 + \cancel{h^2} &= \cancel{h^2} + (R_2+1/2)^2
\\ (2R_1+1)^2 - 2(2R_1+1)R_2 + \bcancel{R_2^2} + \xcancel{1/4} &= \bcancel{R_2^2} +R_2 + \xcancel{1/4}
\\ (2R_1+1)^2 &= (4R_1+3) R_2 \tag{I}
\end{align}
$$

Eliminating $h$ between 2. and 3. by subtracting the equations:

$$
\begin{align}
(R_1+1)^2 + \cancel{h^2} - 1/4 - \cancel{h^2} &= (R_1+R_2)^2 - (R_2+1/2)^2
\\ \cancel{R_1^2} + 2 R_1 + 1 - \xcancel{1/4} &= \cancel{R_1^2} + 2 R_1 R_2 + \bcancel{R_2^2} - \bcancel{R_2^2} - R_2 - \xcancel{1/4}
\\ 2R_1 + 1 &= (2R_1-1)R_2\tag{II}
\end{align}
$$

Eliminating $R_2$ between $(I)$ and $(II)$ by cross-multiplying:

$$
\begin{align}
(2R_1+1)^\bcancel{2}(2R_1-1)\cancel{R_2} &= \bcancel{(2R_1+1)}(4R_1+3)\cancel{R_2}
\\ 4 R_1^2 - 4 R_1 - 4 &= 0 \tag{III}
\end{align}
$$

The latter is indeed the equation that defines the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), so $\,R_1 = \varphi\,$.

Comment: For verification, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=groebnerbasis%5B+%7B2a%2B1-%28b%2Bh%29%2C+%28a%2B1%29%5E2%2Bh%5E2-%28a%2Bb%29%5E2%2C+1%2F4%2Bh%5E2-%28b%2B1%2F2%29%5E2%7D%2C+%7Ba%7D%2C+%7Bb%2Ch%7D+%5D) is WA's solution, which includes the ineligible negative roots.

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  Many thanks!